# Changing anchor to point at data-url attribute of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, anchor

When an `a` tag is pressed on my site's navigation I would like the page to scroll to a div which has a `data-url` attribute which matches the `a` tag's `href`. So the `a` tag would not go to the listed `href`, but to any `div` with a `data-url` attribute which matches the `href`.

The site's home page grabs content from pages in a WordPress back end and displays them as a one-page site.

So far I've tried the below, and had no luck:

```
$('.home #menu-main-nav > li > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $anchor = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr("data-id"));
})
```

I presume I'm missing out looping through the div elements on the page for a matching data-url element?

Example anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/about-us/">About us</a>
```

Example div:

```
<div class="subpage" data-url="http://www.website.com/about-us/">
</div>
```

Comment: `data-id` attribute is for `a` tag or `div` tag ?

Comment: The `data-url` attribute is on the `div` tags but I'm looking to point the `a` tag to them, much like pointing an `a` tag to a url on the same page like `<a href="#idfordivonsamepage">`. Hope this is clarified enough!

Comment: What do you mean by `point a to divs`? Do you need to scroll the page to that div, or do you want to slide that div from the sides?

Comment: When an `a` tag is clicked the page would scroll to the `div` with a `data-url` that matches the `href` of the `a` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scroll the page to the needed section like so:

```
//find all subpages beforehand
var subPages = $('.subpage'),
    scroll_offset = -10; //if the position of the scroll needs tweaking

$('#menu-main-nav').on('click' ,'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $anchor = $(this).attr('href');

    //find the needed div
    var target = subPages.filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('url') == $anchor; //this will return the needed div
    });

    //find the target coordinates
    var position = target.offset();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: position.top + scroll_offset
    }, 500);
})
```

Can be seen live here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L69642ta/

If you don't need to animate to the needed div, simply remove the `.animate()` and make it like this:

```
...
$('html, body').scrollTop(position.top + scroll_offset);
...
```

Can be seen live here:
http://jsfiddle.net/L69642ta/1

Comment: You're a life-saver. I never thought of taking this approach, if I ever come across anyone experiencing this issue I'll point them to this answer. Thanks!